# Select rows in one file based on specific values in the second file (Linux)

Tags: linux

I have two files:

One is "total.txt". It has two columns: the first column is natural numbers (indicator) ranging from 1 to 20, the second column contains random numbers.

```
1 321
1 423
1 2342
1 7542
2 789
2 809
2 5332
2 6762
2 8976
3 42
3 545
... ...
20 432
20 758
```

The other one is "index.txt". It has three columns:(1.indicator, 2:low value, 3: high value)

```
1 400 5000
2 600 800
11 300 4000
```

I want to output the rows of "total.txt" file with first column matches with the first column of "index.txt" file. And at the same time, the second column of output results must be larger than (>) the second column of the "index.txt" and smaller than (<) the third column of the "index.txt".

The expected result is as follows:

```
1 423
1 2342
2 809
2 5332
2 6762
11 ...
11 ...
```

I have tried this:

```
awk '$1==(awk 'print($1)' index.txt) && $2 > (awk 'print($2)' index.txt) && $1 < (awk 'print($2)' index.txt)'  total.txt > result.txt
```

But it failed!

Can you help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Use the `join` command.

Comment: That's not how you execute shell commands from inside `awk`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. Actually, I want to know how to get the value from the second file, otherwise, I can' figure out more complicated questions. I have already updated questions above. I'm new to Linux, Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read both files in the same `awk` script. When you read `index.txt`, store the other columns in an array.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { low[$1] = $2; high[$1] = $3; next }
    $2 > low[$1] && $2 < high[$1] { print }' index.txt total.txt
```

`FNR == NR` is the common `awk` idiom to detect when you're processing the first file.

Comment: Thank you! It takes me a while to understand this. I have checked the `FNR == NR` Now it's clear to me. Thanks again @Barmar

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I explore something new today. I change the format of the `index.txt`, and find that if the first column of different regions are the same, the original code can not work properly (at least one region which has the same indicator with other regions will be missing, please see the above example).@Barmar

Comment: Since the arrays use `indicator` as the index, there can only be one entry for each indicator. You need a 2-dimensional array of `indicator` and `region`, but `awk` doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: It's not fair changing the question. I gave a correct answer for the original question. If you have a different problem you should ask a new question, not change your question.

Comment: Sorry for that @Barmar. But I still accept you as the best answer. It is just convenient for me to edit the question. I apologize. I will edit this question as it was and post a new question. Thank you for help! Here is the new question:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308938/select-rows-in-one-file-based-on-specific-values-in-the-second-file

Comment: Hi, @Barmar, I have already edited the question as it was. Sorry again! And I also hope you can help me with the new question, thank you!  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308938/select-rows-in-one-file-based-on-specific-values-in-the-second-file

Answer (score 0):

Use join like Barmar said:

```
# To join on the first columns
join -11 -21 total.txt index.txt
```

And if the files aren't sorted in lexical order by the first column then:

```
join -11 -21 <(sort -k1,1 total.txt) <(sort -k1,1 index.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks @fivetentaylor. But it seems that the `join` can only combine the  identical join fields of two files. What if the `index.txt` file contains other conditions (eg. the second column in `total.txt` needs to be in a specific range), I will update the question in the original question.